# Install Wireless Driver on Hp G72

Tags: 10.04, wireless, drivers, hp

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my HP G72. All the drivers are installed except my wireless driver. I tried some solutions I saw online but none of them worked for me. Can somebody help me out with it? Thanks.

Comment: Or you can use Jockey-GTK to check any Proprietary driver for your wireless card....

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link 
[Wireless troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html)
or if yu have a wireless driver installed on windows use the following

Using Windows Wireless Drivers

Ubuntu supports a system known as NDISWrapper. This allows you to use a Windows wireless device driver under Ubuntu.

Obtain the Windows Driver for your system and locate the file that ends with .inf.

Install ndisgtk (System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager).

Open ndisgtk (System → Administration → Windows Wireless Drivers).

Select Install new driver.

Choose the location of your Windows .inf file and click Install.

Click OK.

Comment: thnx @Ashu i did that but now when i check on the (System → Administration → Windows Wireless Drivers) it shows Hardware present:Yes but i can't connect to the wireless network still

Comment: what method did you follow? what error r u gettin?